# Perl to static executable on linux

Tags: windows, linux, perl, executable, cross-compiling

I want to create a static executable that will run on a windows machine from a linux machine (ubutu 10.04).

Is there anyway of doing so??

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Perl2Exe from http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php . It is not expensive, but you have to run in windows.

10-1 these programs will run nicely in Wine as they will be using very basic stuff from Windows.

Let us know how it plays out.

Answer (score 2):

No. There was an attempt to make PAR create executables for another OS but, AFAIK, it was not finished. You can try creating PAR executable in Windows inside virtual machine. Install Strawberry Perl and PAR::Packer.

Answer (score 0):

What about [pl2exe](http://code.google.com/p/perl-compiler/source/browse/trunk/script/pl2exe.pl?spec=svn198&r=198)?  It's written in Perl so it should work fine on Linux and still produce a windows exe.